# what can be the best data structure to hold recursive, multi valued and repeated key-value paired data?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Basically its loading of xml data but it has following 3 properties to be satisfied

1. repetitive (key value pair can repeat)
2. multivalued (single key have multiple value)

In both cases I need to preserve the order of data.

Comment: you say "following 3 properties", followed by 2 properties, then referring to "both cases".

Comment: If key value pair are repeating, do you still need to store all the copies of the same value?

Comment: that make as 3rd case @Ravi Yes

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your complexity requirements (or your expected data complexity), but I used once a `multimap<Key, list<Value> >` for some project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C++ programmer but this looks like a linked list of linked lists to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using composite design pattern. [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a65b9b4a-9ccf-4bbf-bc8e-14b554fc8cf3/) has some relevant information for this context.

Answer (score 0):

No single data structure will satisfy all of these properties. You will have to use inheritance and mix data structures at runtime.